# FCM format date in body_loc_args

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a flutter app with firebase backend. Currently I'm just compiling for android.

I'm trying to send a date as argument in a firebase cloud message with a string resource on android

In which format do I need to send the date and how do I format it in the string resource in `strings.xml` on android?

my test setup is just a `sh` script that runs curl with the message payload:

```
DATA='{"notification": {"body_loc_key": "cloudMessage","body_loc_args": ["<mydate>"]}, "data": {"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"}, "to": "<mytoken>"}'
curl https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d "$DATA" -H "Authorization: key=<mykey>"
```

my strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="cloudMessage">
        test: %1$tD
    </string>
</ressources>
```

I can format strings with `%1$s`, but I'm unable to format anything as date with `%1$t`. Also I'm unsure, how to send the date as a string. I tried a unix timestamp and an iso-string.